# Remove all <tr> If does not contain "test" in text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension for the first time and need a little help with my Javascript.

In my popup menu I want a few buttons. Once someone presses this button lets say button "test". I want it to remove every single `<tr>` whom does not contain the word `"test"`.

I am making this because the filter functionality on this website I use a lot is very slow. This way I can filter faster myself by removing the rows instead of the program searching through all of them.

This is what I have so far:

```js
var searchString = 'TEST';
$("#tbody tr td:contains('" + searchString + "')").each(function Tester() {
  if ($(this).text() != searchString) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Remove all rows which don't contain:</p>
<button onclick="Tester()">TEST</button>
```

Comment: There's already an obvious problem. the callback used in the `.each.  function must be anonymous like `.each(function () { /* do something */ })`

Comment: @3Dos it doesn't *have* to be anonymous. This won't cause an error, and will attach the function correctly. It's just completely pointless as the reference to `Tester` will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @RoryMcCrossan . I learned something today :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly don't use inline JS. It's bad practice. Attach event handlers using unobtrusive JS instead.

To fix your actual issue, use the `:contains` selector along `remove()`, something like this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var searchString = $(this).text();
  $("#tbody tr td:contains('" + searchString + "')").closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Remove all rows which don't contain:</p>
<button>TEST</button>

<table>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>TEST</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TEST</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#tbody tr td").each( function () {
    if ( $(this).text().indexOf( searchString ) == -1 ) { //notice the use of indexOf
        $(this).parent().remove();//
    }
});
```

Or you can check the row's `text` itself

```
$("#tbody tr").each( function () {
    if ( $(this).text().indexOf( searchString ) == -1 ) { 
        $(this).remove();//
    }
});
```